# How to connect to an application that using kubernetes and is running in a docker container from local machine?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, portforwarding, ansible-awx

I feel I have created an abomination. The goal of what I am doing is to run a docker image and start the AWX web application an be able to use AWX on my local machine. The issue with this is that AWX uses kubernetes to run. I have created an image that is able to run kubernetes and the AWX application inside a container. The final output after running my bash script in the container to start AWX looks like this:

```
NAMESPACE             NAME                                               READY   STATUS      RESTARTS        AGE
awx-operator-system   awx-demo-586bd67d59-vj79v                          4/4     Running     0               3m14s
awx-operator-system   awx-demo-postgres-0                                1/1     Running     0               4m11s
awx-operator-system   awx-operator-controller-manager-5b4fdf998d-7tzgh   2/2     Running     0               5m4s
ingress-nginx         ingress-nginx-admission-create-pfcqs               0/1     Completed   0               5m33s
ingress-nginx         ingress-nginx-admission-patch-8rghp                0/1     Completed   0               5m33s
ingress-nginx         ingress-nginx-controller-755dfbfc65-f7vm7          1/1     Running     0               5m33s
kube-system           coredns-6d4b75cb6d-4lnvw                           1/1     Running     0               5m33s
kube-system           etcd-minikube                                      1/1     Running     0               5m46s
kube-system           kube-apiserver-minikube                            1/1     Running     0               5m45s
kube-system           kube-controller-manager-minikube                   1/1     Running     0               5m45s
kube-system           kube-proxy-ddnh7                                   1/1     Running     0               5m34s
kube-system           kube-scheduler-minikube                            1/1     Running     0               5m45s
kube-system           storage-provisioner                                1/1     Running     1 (5m33s ago)   5m43s

go to http://192.168.49.2:30085 , the username is admin and the password is XL8aBJPy16ziBau84v63QJLNVw2JGmnb
```

So I believe that it is running and starting properly. The IP address `192.168.49.2` is the IP of one of the kubernetes pods. I have been struggeling to forward the info coming from this pod to my local machine. I have been trying to go from Kubernetes pod -> docker localhost -> local machine local host.

I have tried using `kubectl proxy`, `host.docker.internal` curl and a few other with no success. However I might be using these in the wrong form.

I understand that docker containers run in a very isolated environment so is it possible to forward this information from the pod to my local machine?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The best way is to simply create a `Service` object inside kubernetes, that will expose this application  outside the cluster (all the pods) allowing you to access it easily.

Comment: And I will recommend that you run k8s in a VM, like minikube and don't try to layer docker on top of it, it will only cause complications. You can still run your AWX application in k8s from a docker image, and this will be a cleaner setup.

Comment: Thanks. I am using minikube as part of my image. Using https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/kubernetes-helm-minikube I am a little confused on how I would run AWX in k8s using docker image? Do you have any suggestions for this?